# Better way to send data to server

Tags: json, optimization

I have two ways in which i can send data(json string) to server.

1)`map<key,list>`

eg. `{"components":["ab","bc","cd"],"values":[1,2,3]}`

This represents value of component "ab" is 1.

2) `map<key,values>`

eg. `{"ab":1,"bc":2,"cd":3}`

Now above example is of three components but I want to send thousands of components so which one is more scalable in terms of size and performance.

If you feel I missed some details feel free to ask.

Comment: Are we talking about efficiency in terms of bandwidth or processing power?

Comment: Which language/library are you using?

Comment: I am using java and sending data to server using Writer and OutputStream, please tell me which is better in terms of bandwidth and which one in processing power.

Comment: According to me size of second is always lesser(does not matter number of components sent) so it consume lesser bandwidth, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I've no Idea,how this works in java. The bandwidth should be roughly the same (1 has a little bit more constant overhead).

Answer (score 0):

Server side you will have to do this if you want value for key "bc":

Option 1: `{"components":["ab","bc","cd"],"values":[1,2,3]}`

```
String json = [...] // got json from client
MyJsonObject jo = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyJsonObject.class);

int index = jo.getComponents().indexOf("bc"); // O(n)
int value = jo.getValuess().get(index);       // O(1)
```

Option 2: `{"ab":1,"bc":2,"cd":3}`

```
String json = [...] // got json from client
MyJsonObject jo = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyJsonObject.class);

int value = jo.get("bc");       // O(1) ~ O(n)
```

I believe the *option 2* is better because of better performance. Moreover it is simpler and more readable than *option 1*. Differences in the bandwidth can be neglected.

But **you** should decide what solution is better for **your** application.